# Neo4j generate heatmap data from X and Y coordinates

Tags: neo4j, cypher, heatmap

I need to generate heatmap data in CSV format, something like this:

```
X,Y,OCCURRENCES
269,697,41
199,493,8
125,318,2
205,526,24
261,572,2
```

My neo4j database has an entity called "Point" that contains a date, an X and a Y coordinate and it looks like this:

```
Point: {
  "at": "2018-06-26T06:54:42.671141000+12:00"
  "locationPlanX": 367,
  "locationPlanY": 716  
}
```

I have a query that gives the desired output, it works well with a few thousands of points but it starts to struggle with millions.

Query:

```
MATCH (point:Point)
WHERE datetime("2018-06-22T15:00:00.000000+12:00") <= point.at < datetime("2018-06-23T16:00:00.000000+12:00")
AND point.locationPlanX >= 0
AND point.locationPlanY >= 0
WITH point.locationPlanX as x, point.locationPlanY as y, COUNT(point) AS occurrences
RETURN x, y, occurrences
```

As I said before, the query works well for an hour of data, but it starts to struggle with days/weeks.
Is there any other thing I can do to improve my query? Or any other way to do it?

UPDATE: The 3 properties in the node are indexed.

Comment: Is the `at` value a `datetime` or a string? You should not be able to successfully compare a datetime directly with a string (containing a timestamp).

Comment: at is datetime type

Answer (score 1):

You should create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Point(at)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Point(at);
```

That would allow your query to avoid scanning through every `Point` node to find the ones with acceptable `at` values. This should greatly speed up your query.

Also, if it is not necessary to test `locationPlanX` and `locationPlanY` for non-negativity, eliminate those tests.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Point(at) is already indexed (updated my question) and yes, I need to filter the negative coordinates. locationPlanX and locationPlanY are also indexed though I am not sure if these last two indexes make sense or not.